# Why is my server returning machine name instead of url with my WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, iis-6, hosting

[image: Attached Screenshot of browser]

Why is my server returning machine name instead of url with my WCF Service hosted in IIS6 on windows 2003 x86?

Comment: Your machine name *is* the URL

Comment: No My Machine name is "mytestmachine"

Comment: Issue resolved by added following bold attribute and value

    `<serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"
               **httpsGetUrl="https://myserver.com/"**>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>` service behavior to do that:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
    </serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Parser Error Message: Invalid element in configuration. The extension name 'useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.

Comment: Final Solution: **httpsGetUrl="https://myserver.com/xyz.svc/mex"** solved it perfectly